# TestNG WARN Hookable already set, There was an error in the forked process

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project, which has multiple testng listener classes outside the project(as a dependency and is part of another jar which is referred from Nexus Repo), if I have to exclude one of the listeners or make one of the listeners as default how do I do that?

below are the two listener logs which gets printed in the console

```
[TestNG] [WARN] Hookable already set
ReportLoggerSuiteListner [DEBUG] [XYZ] outputDirectory:/target/surefire-reports (from ISuite)
ReportLoggerSuiteListner [DEBUG] [XYZ] cwd: 
2020-06-02 22:35:24 ReportLoggerSuiteListner [DEBUG] [XYZ] name: Sample
2020-06-02 22:35:24 ReportLoggerSuiteListner [DEBUG] [XYZ] copyToConsole:true
2020-06-02 22:35:24 ReportLoggerUtils [DEBUG] [XYZ] error cleaning trace files directory:
```

```
ReportLoggerSuiteListener [DEBUG] [ABC] outputDirectory: /target/surefire-reports(from ISuite)
2020-06-02 22:35:24 ReportLoggerSuiteListener [DEBUG] [ABC] cwd: 
2020-06-02 22:35:24 ReportLoggerSuiteListener [DEBUG] [ABC] name: Sample
2020-06-02 22:35:24 ReportLoggerSuiteListener [DEBUG] [ABC] copyToConsole:true
```

The surefire plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>

                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- Suite file injection parameter from command line -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Even though its not causing any harm to the test execution build is failing at the runtime for one of the testng listeners with the following error message, which may cause the CI/CD pipeline to break. Whereas the other listener/reporter is fine

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project : Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/File;)V
[ERROR]     at com.xxx.xxx.common.utility.testng.NewFailureReport.copyFileToOutputDirectory(NewFailureReport.java:201)
[ERROR]     at com.xxx.xxx.common.utility.testng.NewFailureReport.generateReport(NewFailureReport.java:51)
[ERROR]     at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1076)
[ERROR]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1035)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
```

Comment: can you provided more info? i don't understand, what do you need?

Comment: @ElDavid Is there a way in which we could disable ITestListener from the dependent jar from pom.xml. There are multiple listeners which gets hooked from the dependency. Let me know if you need more info on this